# Moving Files From One Folder To Another VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to figure out how to move 5 files

settings.txt
settings2.txt
settings3.txt
settings4.txt
settings5.txt

from one folder to another.

Although I know what the file names will be and what folder Name they will be in, I don't know where that folder will be on the Users computer.

My thought process is to use a FolderBrowseDialog which the user can browse to where the Folder is, and then when OK is pressed, it will perform the File copy to the destination folder, overwriting what's there.

**This is what I have so far.**

```
Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim result As Windows.Forms.DialogResult = FolderBrowserImport.ShowDialog()

    If result = DialogResult.OK Then
        FolderPath = FolderBrowserImport.SelectedPath & "\"

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
            FolderPath & "settings.txt", "c:\test\settings.txt", overwrite:=True)

    ElseIf result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Exit Sub

    End If
```

Rather than run this 5 times, is there a way where it can copy all 5 files at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know why IdleMind recommended the approach they did, but it would probably make for a bit more readable code to just list out the file names:

```
Imports System.IO

...



    Dim result = FolderBrowserImport.ShowDialog()

    If result <> DialogResult.OK Then Exit Sub

    For Each s as String in {"settings.txt", "settings2.txt", "settings3.txt", "settings4.txt", "settings5.txt" }

      File.Copy( _
        Path.Combine(FolderBrowserImport.SelectedPath, s), _
        Path.Combine("c:\test", s), _
        True _
      )

    Next s
```

You can swap this fixed array out for a list that VB prepares for you:

```
For Each s as String in Directory.GetFiles(FolderBrowserImport.SelectedPath, "settings*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

  File.Copy(s, Path.Combine("c:\test", Path.GetFilename(s)), True)

Next s
```

Tips:

- It's usually cleaner to do a `If bad Then Exit Sub` than a `If good Then (big load of indented code) End If` - test all your known failure conditions at the start and exit the sub if anything fails, rather than arranging a huge amount of indented code
- Use `Path.Combine` to combine path and filenames etc; it knows how to deal with stray `\` characters
- Use Imports to import namespaces rather than spelling everything out all the time (`System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult` - a winforms app will probably have all the necessaries imported already in the partial class so you can just say `DialogResult`. If you get a red wiggly line, point to the adjacent lightbulb and choose to import System.WIndows/Forms etc)

Comment: Caius Jard, that what exactly what I was looking for. By putting the file names in { } is this called an Array ?

Comment: Yep, that's an array initializer. Full docs are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/how-to-initialize-an-array-variable

Comment: Array initializers aren't arrays per se; they're a shortcut way of *creating an array*. You could have said the long form of  `Dim files(4) As New String` `files(0) = "settings.txt"` `files(1) = "settings2.txt"` ... but using an initializer is a shortcut way to "create an array an return it"- you could conceive that the VB compiler rewrites the initializer into the long form for you. Also, we could have captured it into a variable `Dim files = {"a","b"}` and then said `For Each f In files` - it's just we didn't need to keep the array in a separate variable; only need it for looping over

Comment: Be aware that with the second, shorter code, you won't know if any of the files are missing; it will happily act on only the files that are found by the pattern... which might be none.

Comment: Good point; that might be a positive or negative thing - the former code will crash if it can't find one of the files.. it may also act on more files than the code that has the fixed file name list

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the selected folder, use a `For` loop to build up the names of the files you're looking for.  Use `System.IO.File.Exists()` to see if they are there.  Use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` to properly combine your folders with the filenames.

Here's a full example (without exception handling, which should be added):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If FolderBrowserImport.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim FolderPath As String = FolderBrowserImport.SelectedPath
        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
            Dim FileName As String = "settings" & If(i = 1, "", i) & ".txt"
            Dim FullPathFileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderPath, FileName)
            If System.IO.File.Exists(FullPathFileName) Then
                Dim DestinationFullPathFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine("c:\test", FileName)
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(FullPathFileName, DestinationFullPathFileName, True)
            Else
                ' possibly do something in here if the file does not exist?
                MessageBox.Show("File not found: " & FullPathFileName)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```